# What's the difference between message brokers?

Tags: rabbitmq, google-cloud-platform, message-queue, mqtt, hivemq

I'm confused with different message brokers.

My devices are using MQTT. So far I have looked at HiveMQ, IBM Messagesight, RabbitMQ, google pub and sub, AWS SQS.

What's the difference between HiveMQ(MQTT message broker) and RabbitMQ (or pub and sub, SQS)?

Besides the protocol and cost might be different, is there any difference in their functionalities? And one more question, is IBM messagesight a message broker, is it any different from google pub and sub or rabbit?

I cannot find any information about messagesight.

Answer (score 6):

Generally, you can use Mosquitto, RabbitMQ, HiveMQ or other broker for MQTT.

Mosquitto and RabbitMQ are open source (free), HiveMQ is now (2020) also open source, before you could try it for free. I've only used Mosquitto and RabbitMQ, my comments for them:

- Mosquitto: easy to configure, but we've experienced some instability of it, it just stopped working for no reason after running few days, so we decided to switch to RabbitMQ.
- RabbitMQ: has plugin for MQTT, the configuration is more complicated than mosquitto. It took me a full day to figure out how to use MQTT with SSL login. RabbitMQ comes with a management plugin, which provides a nice GUI (no GUI for mosquitto).